# How to apply filter using a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to apply a filter to my query (accounts.provider = 'z') using the accounts table. The query I have at the moment is not applying the filter correctly, the full list of payments is being added up, regardless of the provider condition. The reason why I'm using table x to join the accounts table is because table t doesn't have the account_id column to allow me to join it with the accounts table.

This is my current query

```
SELECT 
distinct on (x.day) x.day, 
coalesce(pending_payments,0) 
from 
((   SELECT day::date
   FROM    generate_series(timestamp '2017-03-13', current_date + interval '1 week', interval  '1 day') day
   ) d
left JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', payment_date)::date AS day,
        sum(case when payment_amount > 0
    and description not ilike '%credit%'
    and state = 'pending'
    then payment_amount end) as pending_payments
    FROM   payments
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t USING (day) inner join payments on payments.payment_date = t.day) x
inner join accounts on accounts.id = x.account_id and accounts.provider = 'z'

where day <= current_date + interval '1 week'
and day >= current_date - interval'6 months'

ORDER  BY x.day desc
```

Thanks for your help

Updated query based on suggestions in the comments but it's not producing the right outcome (see comments).

```
SELECT 
distinct on (t.day) t.day as day, 
coalesce(pending_payments,0) 
from 
(   SELECT day::date
   FROM    generate_series(timestamp '2017-03-13', current_date + interval '1 week', interval  '1 day') day
   ) d
left JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date AS day,
        sum(case when t.payment_amount > 0
    and t.description not ilike '%credit%'
    and t.state = 'success'
    then t.payment_amount end) as pending_payments
    FROM   payments t 
    inner join payments p on p.payment_date = date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date 
    inner join accounts on accounts.id = p.account_id and accounts.provider = 'z'
    where date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date <= current_date + interval '1 week'
    and date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date >= current_date - interval'1 months'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t  USING (day) 
   

ORDER  BY day desc
```

Comment: is it mysql or PostgreSQL? ,, please remove the wrong tag ...

Comment: Removed the inconsistent database tags, Please add the specific database tag only.

Comment: Apologies this is postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the `pending_payments` (In sub-query) before applying the `accounts.provider = 'z'` condition.

You should replace this code:

```
....
....
left JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', payment_date)::date AS day,
        sum(case when payment_amount > 0
    and description not ilike '%credit%'
    and state = 'pending'
    then payment_amount end) as pending_payments
    FROM   payments
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t USING (day) inner join payments on payments.payment_date = t.day) x
inner join accounts on accounts.id = x.account_id and accounts.provider = 'z'
....
....
```

with

```
....
....
left JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date AS day,
        sum(case when t.payment_amount > 0
    and t.description not ilike '%credit%'
    and t.state = 'pending'
    then t.payment_amount end) as pending_payments
    FROM   payments t
    inner join payments p on p.payment_date = date_trunc('day', t.payment_date)::date
    inner join accounts on accounts.id = p.account_id and accounts.provider = 'z'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t 
....
....
```

Comment: hi thanks for this. any idea why the query just keeps spinning and does not return me a result? I've posted the updated query in the text of the question

Comment: Apply date where clause in sub-query too.

Comment: thanks, updated query again with the date where clause in the sub-query. However, the numbers I'm returned are exactly multiples of the real figures (times 13, 20 etc) - different dates are a different multiple. Mind taking a look please?